# Checkbox dependency

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have two different lists of object. This list is represented on UI like two separated panel with checkboxes. I have a button with some command. How I can bind IsEnabled property in Button for a two object, two different lists. I want to my button enabled only if checked one of checkbox in one list and one of checkbox in another list. I'm working with MVVM pattern and using Prism framework.
Thank you.

Comment: You can bind 2 UI elements to the same ViewModel property.  Create a bool property, and wire up the 2 different checkboxes to this property.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a readonly property in your viewmodel which represents this state, e.g.:

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _c1, _c2;
    public bool Condition1
    {
        get { return _c1; }
        set
        {
            _c1 = value;
            //notify framework
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOtherThingEnabled))
        }
    }

    public bool Condition2
    {
        get { return _c2; }

        set
        {
            _c2 = value;
            //notify framework
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOtherThingEnabled))
        }
    }

    public bool IsOtherThingEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _c1 && _c2; 
        }
    }
    //etc.
}
```

The additional call to `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOtherThingEnabled))` will trigger the framework to update the view bindings for this property.

*note*: some logic to cancel the notifypropertychanged, like `if (_c1 == value) { return; }` is ommited.

*additional note*: it might not fit perfectly, but basically this is the concept; my xaml, WPF is a bit rusty.

As for the XAML binding:

```
<!-- assuming your viewmodel is bound to the view -->
<button IsEnabled="{Binding IsOtherThingEnabled}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @DraganMilovac93: your welcome. Keep in mind that thanks is expressed by upvoting and/or marking as answer ;-)